# How to communicated with android ril daemon directly

Tags: android, android-source, ril

I want to communicate with android RIL daemon with my daemon directly.

Could you tell me how to do it without using telephony layer.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you shouldn't! Let the Android framework handle ril, or you may put the daemon in some undefined state.

With that disclaimer, you need to look into

```
./frameworks/base/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/gsm 
./frameworks/base/telephony/java/android/telephony/gsm
```

For specifics.
The actual commands are be passed through the rild socket, so you will also need to run as root or belong to the radio group to get access.